# ESPAsyncDNSServer cannot find AsyncUDP anymore

Tags: esp32, platformio

I'm using [this](https://github.com/guestisp/ESP32AsyncDNSServer) ESP32AsyncDNSServer library on my ESP32 application.
Suddenly (I'm not sure what I did) it does not compile anymore:

> .pio/libdeps/Aphrodite/ESPAsyncDNSServer/src/ESPAsyncDNSServer.h:8:10: fatal error: AsyncUDP.h: No such file or directory

Here the related code of the library:

```
#ifdef ARDUINO_ARCH_ESP32 
#ifndef Stream_h
#include <Stream.h>
#endif
#include <AsyncUDP.h>
#else
#include <ESPAsyncUDP.h>
#endif
```

but of course `AsyncUDP.h` *does* exist:

> /home/mark/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/libraries/AsyncUDP/src/AsyncUDP.h

What could prevent the compiler to find it?

Answer (score 1):

for whatever reason, adding this to your platformio.ini `env` section helps:

```ini
[env]
lib_compat_mode = strict # default is "soft"
```

I guess the more clean version would be to add this to your `lib_deps`

```ini
lib_deps = 
    ESP32 Async UDP # important! otherwise "AsyncUDP.h" blabla is missing..
    <your libs following>
```